# Node js Bash Terminal send environment value from file

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I was wondering if I can read a file and send in commands like in terminal like in node, maven, python, gradle or etc to avoid large terminal string o hard code

I tried this command, the file `index.txt` has a simple string and the `index.js` has a console log with process.env.FILE just I want to know how can I send a file like env value

```
FILE=<(cat index.txt) node index.js
```

The result of the command is `/dev/fd/63`

Please help is for run a docker easy and do it immutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it in two steps:

```
export FILE=$(cat index.txt)
node index.js
```

First line will set the FILE environment variable with the output of the cat command. And as it is exported it is available to the node process.

Comment: It was i expected for node, thank you but now i need to search how i can do it in gradle or maven